# Print every line starting with "X"

Tags: bash, terminal

What command can I use that prints every line that starts with a string? For example:

test.txt

```
Hello world!
How are you?
I am doing fine.
blah blah blah.
```

```
echo test.txt startsWith H
```

prints

```
Hello world!
How are you?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -E '^H' file
```